# MVC3 - The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've come across a bit of a weird problem I can't make sense of.  One of my controllers has stopped working, but if I rename it then it works fine.  I don't have any special routing wrapped around this controller, it just uses my default.

To give specifics, I have a controller called "Kangaroo".  In the browser, if I go to {server}/Kangaroo, then I get the "The Resource cannot be found" message.  However, if I go to {server}/Kangaroo/Index, then my page loads as normal.  I don't have this problem on any of my other controllers, only this one.  If I rename the controller (and my view folder) to "Kangaroo2", then it works perfectly fine.

Here is my route:

```
public class RouteDefinitions {
    public static void AddRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("Resources", 
                        "cache/{action}/{key}/{version}/{type}", 
                        new { controller = "Cache", 
                              action = "CacheContent", 
                              key = "", 
                              version = "", 
                              type = "" });
        routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                        new {
                              controller = "Home",
                              action = "Index",
                              id = ""
                             } // Parameter defaults
                       );
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on here?  I thought it might just be a weird visual studio thing, but restarting did not correct the issue.

Comment: Where's the route that handles the 'server' attribute? Without a route specifically to handle `{server}/Kangaroo`, it's going to fall through to your Default route, which incidentally will work.  Have you tried The RouteDebugger from Phil Haack to see what's going on (or Glimpse?) http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Sorry, {server} is the address to my server.  ie:  http://localhost/...

Comment: I tried Glimpse, but nothing comes up when I get the Resource not found message.  On all the other routes (even my renamed one), Glimpse works fine.

Comment: Even more, I tried creating a special route just for "Kangaroo", but still ran into the issue

Comment: Have you tried the magic clean solution -> rebuild all trick?

Comment: @Tommy - Just tried it, but still no change.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out what the problem was.  There was a folder in my project called "/Kangaroo".  I guess it was treating it like a script or other content. Since the path existed it was attempting to load something from the path.

Comment: Thanks! I just had this same problem. The folder was created dynamically when it created a file, and for the life of me I couldn't figure out why it just stopped working!